# Getting "Stream is Closed" IOException when requesting a fairly long response

Tags: java, android, gzip, ioexception

Update : I know get the same error no matter how little data I try to receive. Any thoughts and suggestions that could help me solve this would be greatly appreciated.

I am in the proces of trying to retrieve a list of UserIDs from a list of Members in a web service. Unfortunately after having received only a few Members I get a "Stream is Closed" IOException. This is the first time I try retrieving a stream of this magnitude(We're talking +100 members) and also the first time I'm receiving this error.

The error in question :

[IOException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYF1Y.png)

The code where the exception occurs :

```
private void setupRequest(OAuthRequest request) 
{
    request.setConnectionKeepAlive(true);
    request.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    request.addHeader("accept", "image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, */*");
//  request.addHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    request.addHeader("user-agent", m_sIDENTIFIER);
}

private String readStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException 
{
    String sReturn = "";
    if(stream != null)
    {
        final BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
        final StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer();
        String line = bufReader.readLine();
        if(line != null)
        {
            s2.append(line);
            while((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                s2.append('\n');
                s2.append(line);
            }
        }
        bufReader.close();
        sReturn = s2.toString();
    }
    return sReturn;
}

private InputStream getResultStream(Response response) throws IOException
{
    InputStream resultStream = null;
    if(response != null)
    {
        String encoding = response.getHeader("Content-Encoding");
        if((encoding != null) && (encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")))
        {
            Log.d("Stream :", "Read GZIP");

        } else if ((encoding != null) && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("deflate")) {
            resultStream = new InflaterInputStream(response.getStream(), new Inflater(true));
            Log.d("Stream :", "Read Deflated.");
        } else {
            resultStream = response.getStream();
            Log.d("Stream :","Read Normal.");
        }       
    }

    return resultStream;
}
```

Any idea on what's causing the issue ? Is there a limit to how much data I get receive?

Answer (score 0):

I think your connection gets time out.

```
request.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Increase seconds

Answer (score 0):

I would say the remote server closed the connection (due to an error?). From your log I can see that the response is gzipped. Were your successful responses also gzipped?

Comment: Nope. I've never accepted gzip encoding. I thought maybe that was the issue but the stream still gets closed before all of my data is retrieved.